# Adding Joptionpane in shutdownHook

Tags: java

Is there any way to show joptionpane in shutdownhook
i.e I need to show a confirmdailog in my shutdownhook event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is, it won't help you.

The shutdown hooks are invoked asynchronously as part of the JVM shutdown, so a "confirm" dialog won't really confirm anything as you can't halt or reverse the shutdown process.

Comment: Well, you can prevent the JVM from actually terminating by having a thread `wait()` forever but right, you can’t prevent an already running shutdown. :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you want is not a shutdown hook, but a "really quit?" JOptionPane. If so, here's an example of how to do it:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ConfirmToCloseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Really quit?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Hello world"));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not possible to do when the JVM is closed as a result of the user logging off. The AWT subsystem will be closed and there is nothing you can do about that.

Answer (score 1):

A shutdown hook is supposed to execute quickly. Waiting for a user to make a decision is not the kind of action a shutdown hook is meant for. A shutdown hook in an interactive program does not make sense. The real use case for shutdown hooks is for releasing resources and other housekeeping when the JVM is terminated abnormally.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want some sort of prompt when the user finishes with the program but hasn't done some commit action (close a document with unsaved changes). If that is the case, I would put a WindowListener on the window whose closing should trigger the prompt and override windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {...} to show your JOptionPane. According to the JavaDocs you can override the windowClosing at this time. This gives you an opportunity to have a "save, discard, cancel" diaglog for documents with unsaved changes.